# How to add a parent collection in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I guess there's no way to make a parent collection in firestore.
However, There might be the solution, so I post this.

My DB is now like below.

`+ categories
       + stores
       + counters`

Business model's changed so I need to change db model to like this.

`Countries
      + U.S
        + Cities
          + LA
            + categories
            + stores
            + counters
          + NewYork
            + categories
         ...`

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to move documents around into a new structure.  You will have to write code to restructure all your documents and collections to be organized the way you want by individually reading the existing documents, writing a new document, and deleting the original.